# Both #IfWinActive "something" and #If True at once

Tags: autohotkey

I want multiple hotkeys to work only if certain window is active and if a variable is equal 1.
Something like

`#IfWinActive Game
#if var==1 ; assuming it doesn't close 
...
#if`

Is it possible to achieve it without putting `if` statement into every hotkey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ordinary `WinActive` function instead of the `#IfWinActive` directive to combine the two conditions, like this:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class Game") and var==1
    <hotkey1>
    <hotkey2>
    <hotkey3>
#If
```

(Note for context: my original answer was totally off-base, because I hadn't realized that the various directives in the `#If` family are mutually exclusive, so that you can't usefully nest them.)

Comment: Somehow hotkeys are active always when var==1. It doesn't matter which window is active. I've just tried it on ahk v1.1.22.07. 
Also reversing #IfWinActive and #If only makes it sensitive to which window is active and it ignores var. 
It seems like each #If(...) closes the previous.

Comment: That's what I get for not testing my assumptions.  Editing the solution to something that actually works.